# Given any number, get a consistent value between 1 and 10

Tags: ruby

How can I turn any number into a value between 1 and 10?

For example given 123, do an operation that returns the same value between 1 and 10 every time.

I am using this to assign 10 different colors to users by their ID. I need a function that will always give the same 1-10 color value for that user's ID.

I thought I could use the modulo operator for something like this, but haven't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use modulus of 10, and then add one (because mod range is exclusive):

```
(123 % 10) + 1 # => 4
(124 % 10) + 1 # => 5
```

If you want less cyclic results, you could hash the number before applying modulus:

```
(123.to_s.hash % 10) + 1 # => 10
(124.to_s.hash % 10) + 1 # => 7
```

Comment: awesome, will accept when timer is up. Is there a way to make consecutive values within the same group of 10 not return the same value?

Comment: For the second examples, (`(123.to_s.hash % 10) + 1 # => 10`), I'm getting different results every time I reload my interpreter. Maybe try multiplying the number by some arbitrary number (7?), then modulo 10.